# Confused about openGL version

Tags: c++, opengl

I updated my graphics card driver to support openGL 4 so that deprecated functions like glBegin wont work. However, when I run a simple triangle program, glBegin still works like before. Is glBegin still supported by openGL 4 or did I miss some step in upgrading to openGL 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply using a driver that supports OpenGL 4.x does not mean that you will lose the functionality of earlier versions. Beginning with OpenGL 3.2 the concept of **Core** and **Compatibility** profiles were introduced, and this is where the separation between modern and deprecated actually comes into play.

In a **Core** profile, the things you mentioned such as `glBegin` are invalid. However, in a **Compatibility** profile, you can continue to mix-and-match deprecated parts of the API with new parts. The vast majority of new OpenGL features are not guaranteed to work in conjunction with the deprecated parts of the API, in large part because most new features are related to GLSL and the programmable pipeline in some way.

Now things get a little bit more complicated when you discuss a platform like Mac OS X. Beginning with OS X 10.7, Apple began supporting OpenGL 3.2. However, they designed their implementation in such a way that the ***ONLY*** way to access OpenGL 3.2 functionality was to get a **Core** profile. They continue to support a legacy OpenGL 2.1 implementation so that old software does not have to be re-written, but in order to take advantage of any OpenGL 3.2+ features on OS X you have to forefit all deprecated functionality.

---

In fact, platforms are generally designed so that you actually have to do *extra* work during context creation in order to get a **Core** profile. Unless you specifically request **Core**, you will get **Compatibility** (or in the case of OS X, an implementation of OpenGL 2.1). It is a way of making the whole deprecation model as painless as possible for existing software.

Answer (score 2):

"deprecated" doesn't necessarily means that "it will not work", it means "you should not use it because the standard say so", the vendor is free to implement what it wants to sell with the hardware; and many brands still offer deprecated OpenGL contexts and functions in their own libraries.